# $this->{var} to getattr() code translation

Tags: python, php

I'm currently learning python, coming from PHP and i'm trying to "translate" my previous code in php to python and i'm more or less stuck.

i found out that $this->{var} is similar to getattr(self, var_name) but i haven't gotten any further.

my code looks like this in php:

```
public function toArray() {
    return [
        'title' => $this->title,
        'firstname' => $this->firstname,
         'lastname' => $this->lastname,
         'street' => $this->street,
         'zip' => $this->zip,
         'city' => $this->city
    ];
}
```

i'm not sure if this would equal to this in python:

```
#initializer
def __init__ (self, title, firstname, lastname, street, zip, city):
        self.title = ""
        self.firstname = ""
        self.lastname = ""
        self.street = ""
        self.city = ""
        self.zip = ""

def toArray()
    return [
        "title" => getattr(self, "title")
        "firstname" => getattr(self, "firstname")
        #and so on...
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the array format you're using may not be the best for this situation.
use `{}` if you would use `=>` is php.

Also, using `getattr()` is not needed since you can simply put `self.varName` instead of `getattr(self, varName)`.

```
def toArray():
    retval = {
        title: self.title
        firstname: self.firstname
        #and so on...
    }
    return retval
```

Whether or not you store `retval` as a variable is your choice, but personally, I find it more organised.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the Python syntax a bit:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.arr = list(args)

    def get_array(self):
        return self.arr

a = MyClass('hello', 'hi')

print(a.arr)
print(a.get_array())
```

Output:

```
['hello', 'hi']
['hello', 'hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

`getattr` is not needed here since the object is aware of its variable.

Just to be clear: the below code is part of a class. Not a stand alone function.

```
class my_class(object):
  # can add different amount of argument in the constructor
  def __init__(self, title, firstname): 
    self.title = title
    self.firstname = firstname

  def toArray(self)
      return [
        self.title,
        self.firstname,
        #and so on...
    ]
```